# PHP get hash after question mark

Tags: php, url, text, hash, get

How i can get a hash or any text from URL after the question mark.
For example `"http://mediafire.com/?lmle92c5l50uuy5"`
I want to get the hash **"lmle92c5l50uuy5"**

Answer (score 9):

Try [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/%24_SERVER) superglobal if you want to get "hash" for current URL:

```
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

---

If you really need to parse not your URL, you might also use [`strstr()`](http://php.net/strstr) + [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/ltrim):

```
$url = "http://mediafire.com/?lmle92c5l50uuy5";

echo ltrim(strstr($url, '?'), '?');
```

Shows:

```
lmle92c5l50uuy5
```

---

Also possible to use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) (as mentioned in @**Shubham**'s answer), but make it shorter with [`list()`](http://php.net/list) language construction:

```
$url = "http://mediafire.com/?lmle92c5l50uuy5";

list(, $hash) = explode('?', $url);

echo $hash;
```

Comment: A Q from 2013, this answer is still relevant in 2022, for ordering listings on headers in my case. Will use it all over the place from now on!

Answer (score 4):

Use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$arr = explode("?", "http://mediafire.com/?lmle92c5l50uuy5");
$hash = $arr[1];
```

Or,

You can use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) too.

```
$hash = parse_url("http://mediafire.com/?lmle92c5l50uuy5", PHP_URL_QUERY);
```